# ArangoDB unknown option --rocksdb.encryption-keyfile

Tags: docker, encryption, arangodb, rocksdb

I'm using ArangoDB 3.4.4 in a docker container (pulled from Docker Hub) and I'm attempting to implement encryption for the rocksdb engine as outlined on this page: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/operations/security/encryption-at-rest/

I've configured my docker-compose.yml file with this start up command:

```
command: 'arangod --rocksdb.encryption-keyfile=key.txt --server.storage-engine=rocksdb'
```

However it seems to ignore the --server.storage-engine flag and says it's choosing the default engine. But the larger issue is that it gives me the following error for the --rocksdb.encryption-keyfile flag:

```
Error while processing command-line options for arangod:
   unknown option '--rocksdb.encryption-keyfile'
```

If I run an arangod --help command the --rocksdb.encryption-keyfile option that is shown in the documentation doesn't seem to exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual page you referenced states that

> This feature is only available in the Enterprise Edition

As the server in your case does not understand the option, I am sure you are using the community version.
whether the server is an enterprise or a community build can be detected by running the `--version` command on the server executable.
This will show either "community" or "enterprise".

Comment: Facepalm!! That's the issue, thanks for helping me read an obvious blue note! ;)